# Print name of Dictionary used in a list rather than it's values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have defined a couple of dictionaries that I am then referencing in a list. I would like to use the name of the dictionaries as a variable rather it's values. My code (which resolves to the dictionary values, not it's name) is this:

```
prem_year_map = {
 1999: 2,
 2000: 85,
 2001: 191,
 2002: 299,
 2003: 429,
 2004: 594,
 2005: 836,
 2006: 667,
 2007: 1256,
 2008: 1539,
 2009: 1849,
 2010: 2458,
 2011: 2935,
 2012: 3389,
 2013: 3853,
 2014: 4311, }

year_tournament_map = {
    1999: 26,
    2000: 114,
    2001: 243,
    2002: 421,
    2003: 579,
    2004: 903,
    2005: 1291,
    2006: 1645,
    2007: 2175,
    2008: 2689,
    2009: 3419,
    2010: 4940,
    2011: 5861,
    2012: 6978,
    2013: 8273,
}


tournament_list = [prem_year_map,year_tournament_map]

for x in tournament_list:
    print x
```

I'm using the dictionary name in an if statement in my code later on. Can anyone advise me what the syntax I need here is please?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is impossible. When you add the dictionary to the list, what you've actually done is add a pointer to the dictionary to the list. The variable name you used is also another pointer to the dictionary. In fact, you could have an infinite number of pointers to the same dictionary, so there's no way of getting them back.

What you want to do is use a dictionary instead of a list. If order is important to you, use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes). Then you can map names (keys) to values (dictionaries).

Comment: If you have the namespace containing the dictionary variables in question, you can map names to references that way, and then test using 'is' operator, as in my answer. It may not be the best way to do whatever's being done, but this appears to be what is being asked.

Answer (score -1):

You can identify a dictionary object as follows:

```
if d is prem_year_map:
```

Also, you can do something like this (assuming the dicts are defined in the same file, outside a function):

```
list_of_dicts= ['prem_year_map', 'year_tournament_map']  # etc
selected_dictname = list_of_dicts[n]

if selected_dictname == 'prem_year_map':
    yadda_yadda()

# access the dict
selected_dict = globals()[selected_dictname]  # look it up by name
val = selected_dict[2004]      #looks up entry.
```

If you have a dictionary `d` and a string (containing variable name) `dname`, and you want to check if they refer to the same dictionary:

```
if d is globals()[dname]:
```